# Is the assumption (the set is not empty) really needed for my proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

Let $A$ be a set. I want to prove that the set is infinite. I have used the proof by contradiction. First of all I have noticed that the set is not empty and after that I have assumed that the set is finite and then I get a contradiction.

My **question** is: Is the assumption **the set is not empty** really needed for my proof or one can omit this step.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more.  Can you post more about $A$ so the question is more complete?

Comment: @Paul: You can take $A$ the set of rational numbers in the interval $(0,1)$. But I am seeking the general case. You can consider $A$ the set of primes...etc.

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. For example, if $A$ is a set of reals and you can easily show that $A$ has no maximal element, then it follows that $A$ is infinite *provided* it is not empty. In such a situation you better also prove that $A$ is not empty.

Comment: In general, if your proof goes "Assume $A$ is finite. Let $x \in A$...", then yes, you need that the set is non-empty.

Comment: It's really not possible to answer the question in "the general case." Either you needed to use the assumption or you did not. If you needed to use the assumption, then the assumption was needed, and if you did not need to use it, then it was not needed. It's impossible to say more than that without knowing more about the proof.

Answer (score 5):

Call $X = \{n \in \mathbb{N}| n < 0\}$ (*yes*, the negative natural numbers!). You can prove from the axioms of the natural numbers that there is no natural number $n$ such that $n+1=0$. So if $n<0$, then $n+1<1$ and $n+1\neq 0$, so $n+1 < 0$. So if $\exists n \in X$ then $X$ is infinite!

Answer (score 1):

An empty set is usually considered to be finite.

However if your "it can't be finite" proof actually only proves "it can't be *nonempty* finite" (for example because you need to pick an element from it as part of the proof or you're using an induction that can only start at $1$), then you'd still need a separate "it can't be empty" step.